# A bash loop with braces?

Tags: bash, for-loop, syntax

I stumbled across this oddity and can't quite figure out why it works:

```
$ for ((i=0;i<8;i++)) {
>   printf '%d...' "$i";
> }; echo
0...1...2...3...4...5...6...7...
```

A `for` loop in bash using *brace* syntax? I can't reproduce this using a non-arithmetic `for` loop at all, and the manpage and `help` both seem to require the `do`:

```
$ help for
<SNIP>
for ((: for (( exp1; exp2; exp3 )); do COMMANDS; done
    Arithmetic for loop.

    Equivalent to
        (( EXP1 ))
        while (( EXP2 )); do
            COMMANDS
            (( EXP3 ))
        done
```

Hmm, so if I just…

```
$ ((i=0)); while ((i<8)) { printf '%d...' "$i"; ((i++)); }
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `{'
```

Nope!

Is this braced `for-loop` syntax

1. Documented anywhere (official?)
2. A legitimate different way to represent an arithmetic for loop in Bash?
3. Just something I'm missing about how a "normal" arithmetic for loop is interpreting the input?

*P.S. – This was tested on OS X Mavericks with both a homebrew-installed Bash 4.2.45(2)-release as well as the vanilla 3.2.51(1)-release.*

Comment: AFAIK, it is a largely undocumented hack in Bash, probably needed for compatibility with the Bourne shell which also supported the brace notation, also undocumented.  It is not peculiar to Mac OS X; it works like that on Ubuntu 12.04 too.  It doesn't seem to work with `while` loops or `until` loops, though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How do you write an arithmetic `for` loop in Bourne shell syntax? The closest thing I have is `dash`, and I'm unable to find or guess the syntax.

Comment: If you actually bothered to read the documentation that was posted in that answer that you simply downvoted out of hand, you would have read that both `{ }` and `do done` are both command grouping constructs. They're not generally interchangeable, but they are in the context of loops and if statements.

Comment: It is an optional way of writing the body of the `for` loop; the condition would be written differently in Bourne shell, but you could write things like `for i in 1 2 3; { echo $i; }` in Bourne shell, or use `do` in place of `{` and `done` in place of `}`.  (I'd forgotten that it existed until your question reminded me of it; I've never used it seriously because it was not documented and hence not guaranteed to be supported.)

Comment: @Sammitch It's explicitly *not* a structure for grouping commands [according to POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_09_12). I would've happily reversed my downvote and even accepted the given answer if the poster had wanted to adjust it.

Comment: @Sammitch: the now-deleted answer was not accurate.  The `do...done` construct cannot be used where `{ ... }` can be used; you can only use `do ... done` after a `for`, `while` or `until` loop, whereas you can write `{ echo Hi; }` anywhere a command could appear (e.g. `if { echo Hi; }; then echo Lo; fi`.  You can't do that with `do` and `done`.

Comment: Sigh. Now I have a (presumably) [retaliatory downvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92942/retaliatory-downvoting). Is there some way I can improve the question?

Comment: The question is fine. Sadly, there's not a lot you can do about a single down-vote.  If you get a rash of down-votes, you can ask the moderators to investigate; or the automatic systems may spot the problem too.

Comment: *<rubs hands together>* This sort of undocumented hack is just [perfect for playing code-golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Transferring some comments into an answer:

AFAIK, it is a largely undocumented hack in Bash, probably needed for compatibility with the Bourne shell which also supported the brace notation, also undocumented. It is not peculiar to Mac OS X; it works like that on Ubuntu 12.04 too. It doesn't seem to work with `while` loops or `until` loops in Bash, though.

> *How do you write an arithmetic for loop in Bourne shell syntax?*

It is an optional way of writing the body of the `for` loop; the condition would be written differently in Bourne shell, but you could write things like

```
for i in 1 2 3
{
    echo $i
}
```

in Bourne shell, or use `do` in place of `{` and `done` in place of `}`.

(I'd forgotten that it existed until your question reminded me of it; I've never used it seriously because it was not documented and hence not guaranteed to be supported.)

The `do ... done` construct cannot be used where `{ ... }` can be used; you can only use `do ... done` after a `for`, `while` or `until` loop, whereas you can write `{ echo Hi; }` anywhere a command could appear (e.g. `if { echo Hi; }; then echo Lo; fi`. You can't do that with `do` and `done`.

The best way to check the veracity of this answer is likely to be to download the [Heirloom Bourne Shell](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html) from the Heirloom Project.

---

I've downloaded the source code for the Heirloom Bourne Shell (a CVS repository) and built it, and tested it.  It does indeed accept the braces after the for loop, and refuses to recognize them as surrogates for `do` and `done` after an `until` or `while` loop.