# Alternative for-loop construct

Tags: bash, shell, sh, language-lawyer, language-history

**General comment:** any new answer which gives a new and useful insight into this question will be rewarded with a bonus.

---

The [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html) mentions that Bash supports the
following for-loop constructs:

```
for name [ [in [words ...] ] ; ] do commands; done
for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; do commands ; done
```

Surprisingly, the following for-loop constructs are also valid:

```
for i in 1 2 3; { echo $i; }
for ((i=1;i<=3;++i)); { echo $i; }
```

These unusual constructs are not documented at all. Neither the [Bash
manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html), the [Bash man-pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) nor [The Linux Documentation
Project](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html#sect_09_01) make any mention of these constructs.

When investigating the [language grammar](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y?h=bash-5.0#n805) one can see that using
open-and-close braces (`{ commands; }`) as an alternative to `do commands; done` is a valid construct that is implemented for both
for-loops and select statements and dates back to [Bash-1.14.7](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/)
<sup>[1]</sup>.

The other two loop-constructs:

```
until test-commands; do consequent-commands; done
while test-commands; do consequent-commands; done
```

do not have this alternative form.

---

Since a lot of shell-languages are related, one can find that these
constructs are also defined there and mildly documented. The [KSH manual](http://man.openbsd.org/ksh) mentions:

> For historical reasons, open and close braces may be used instead of `do` and `done` e.g.
>
> ```
> for i; { echo $i; }
> ```

while ZSH implements and [documents](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Alternate-Forms-For-Complex-Commands) similar alternatives for the other loop-constructs, but with limitations. It states:

> For the `if`, `while` and `until` commands, in both these cases the
> test part of the loop must also be suitably delimited, such as by
> `[[ ... ]]` or `(( ... ))`, else the end of the test will not be recognized.

---

**Question:** What is the origin of this construct and why is
this not propagated to the other loop-constructs?

---

**Update 1:** There are some very [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63247449/alternate-for-loop-construct#comment111847043_63247449) and [educational](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63247449/alternate-for-loop-construct#comment111901747_63247449) comments below
this post pointing out that this is an undocumented Bourne Shell feature which seems to be the result of a C-vs-sh language battle in the early days.

---

**Update 2:** When asking the question: *Why is this language feature not documented?* to the [Gnu Bash mailinglist](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2020-08/msg00058.html), I received the following answer from Chet Ramey (current lead-developer of GNU bash):

> It's never been documented. The reason bash supports it (undocumented) is
> because it was an undocumented Bourne shell feature that we implemented
> for compatibility. At the time, 30+ years ago, there were scripts that used
> it. I hope those scripts have gone into the dustbin of history, but who
> knows how many are using this construct now.
>
> I'm going to leave it undocumented; people should not be using it anyway.

---

**Related questions/answers:**

- [A bash loop with braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22619510/8344060)
- [Hidden features of Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/211378/8344060) ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8870060/8344060))
- [[U&L] What is the purpose of the “do” keyword in Bash for loops?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306940/273492)

---

<sub>**Footnotes:** <sup>[1]</sup> I did not find earlier versions, I do believe it predates this</sub>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> [W]hy is this not propagated to the other loop-constructs?

Braced forms of **while** and **until** commands would be syntactically ambiguous because you can't separate **test-commands** from **consequent-commands** without having a distinctive delimiter between them as they are both [defined by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_09) to be **compound [lists](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03)**.

For example, a shell that supports such constructs can choose either one of the brace groups in the command below as **consequent-commands** and either way it would be a reasonable choice.

```
while true; { false; }; { break; }
```

Because of its ambiguous form, this command can be translated to either of the below; neither is a more accurate translation than the other, and they do completely different things.

```sh
while true; do
    false
done
break
```

```sh
while true; { false; }; do
    break
done
```

The **for** command is immune to this ambiguity because its first part—a variable name optionally followed by **in** and a list of words, or a special form of the `((` compound command—can easily be distinguished from the brace group that forms its second part.

Given that we already have a consistent syntax for **while** and **until** commands, I don't really see any point in *propagating* this alternate form to them.

Wrt its origin, see:

- [Characteristical common properties of the traditional Bourne shells](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/bourne/common.html#not),
- [Stephen Bourne's talk at BSDCon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kEJoWfobpA&t=2095),
- [Unix v7 source code, `sh/cmd.c`](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/sh/cmd.c).